# Storing list of custom objects in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Started to learn asp.net and DB manipulations. Trying to implement some simple functionality - two models, one has list of references to another.

Here is an error that I currently get:

> An exception occurred while initializing the database. See the InnerException for details.
>
> Inner exception:
>   Unable to determine a valid ordering for dependent operations. Dependencies may exist due to foreign key constraints, model requirements, or store-generated values.

My models:

```
public class Killer
{
        public Killer(string name, string biography)
        {
            Name = name;
            Biography = biography;
            KillerId = Guid.NewGuid();
        }

        public Guid KillerId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Biography { get; set; }

        public virtual Contract Contract { get; set; }
}

public class Contract
{
        public Contract(Status status, Killer target, string description, params Killer[] targets)
        {
            ContractId = Guid.NewGuid();
            this.status = status;
            Target = target;
            Description = description;

            Killers = new HashSet<Killer>();
            foreach (var t in targets) Killers.Add(t);

        }

        public Guid ContractId { get; set; }

        public enum Status { active, done, failed, rejected, abandoned }
        public Status status { get; set; }

        public Killer Target { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }

        //[ForeignKey("ContractID")]
        public virtual ICollection<Killer> Killers { get; set; }
}
```

In context I initialize db with lists of objects

```
public class KillerContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Killer> Killers { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Contract> Contracts { get; set; }
}
```

In controller I do:

```
KillerContext k = new KillerContext();

public ActionResult Index()
{
    var contracts = k.Contracts.ToList();
    ViewBag.contracts = contracts;
    return View();
}
```

In `Global.asax`:

```
Database.SetInitializer(new KillerContextInitialization());
```

Here is how I enter first data in db:

```
public sealed class KillerContextInitialization : DropCreateDatabaseAlways<KillerContext>
{
    protected override void Seed(KillerContext db)
    {
        List<Killer> killers = new List<Killer>();
        //List<Contract> contracts = new List<Contract>();

        killers.Add(new Killer(name: "Ivan Firstein", biography: "He was born in the shadows."));
        killers.Add(new Killer(name: "Oleg Gazmanov", biography: "test man"));
        db.Contracts.Add(new Contract(
                Contract.Status.active,
                killers.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Name == "Ivan Firstein"),
                "KILL OR BE KILLED. As always with love.",
                killers.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Name == "Oleg Gazmanov")
                ));

        db.Killers.AddRange(killers);
        base.Seed(db);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this code-first or database first?

Comment: It is code first. was done based on some article about entity framework

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find out that problem was in `public Killer Target { get; set; }`
When i was adding data, that field was considered as `NOT NULL`, and all what i need to do, is save changes after filling killers, like so:

```
 public sealed class KillerContextInitialization : DropCreateDatabaseAlways<KillerContext>
    {
        protected override void Seed(KillerContext db)
        {
            List<Killer> killers = new List<Killer>();


            killers.Add(new Killer(name: "Ivan Firstein", biography: "He was born in the shadows."));
            killers.Add(new Killer(name: "Oleg Gazmanov", biography: "test man"));

            db.SaveChanges(); // - save killers first, then add them to contract
            db.Contracts.Add(new Contract(
                    Contract.Status.active,
                    killers.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Name == "Ivan Firstein"),
                    "KILL OR BE KILLED. As always with love.",
                    killers.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Name == "Oleg Gazmanov")
                    ));

            db.Killers.AddRange(killers);
            base.Seed(db);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need add ForeignKey attribute for killer Model, and store this key in property ContractId:

```
public class Killer
{
    [ForeignKey(nameof(ContractId)]  //Name of added property in line below
    public Contract Contract { get; set; } //no need "virtual"
    public Guid? ContractId { get; set; }

    // other properties...
}

public class Contract
{
        [ForeignKey("ContractId")] //Name of added property in Killer Model
        public virtual ICollection<Killer> Killers { get; set; }

        // other code... 
}
```

**EDIT**

You should do something similar to the Contract.Target property:

```
[ForeignKey(nameof(TargetId)]
public Killer Target { get; set; }
public Guid TargetId { get; set; }
```

For enum types you should add attributes like this:

```
[Column(nameof(status), TypeName = "int")]
public Status status { get; set; }
```

Comment: Still has same error... It appears on Index() when casting .ToList(); Also generated DB has no data in it